# Split atom grammar into multiple files

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, textmate, atom-editor, cson

Is it possible to split an Atom cson grammar file into multiple files? eg

```
language.cson
```

would turn into:

```
language.cson
->language.types.cson
->language.statements.cson
```

perhaps something like:

```
'repository':
    'types': 'language.types.cson'
    'statements': 'language.statements.cson'
'patterns': [
    include: '#types'
    include: '#statements'
]
```